Has the lowest eigenvalue of a self-adjoint linear operator in a finite Hilbert space multiplicity 1 if the n'th sequence fulfills the same condition?
The setup:
Consider the parametrized self-adjoint linear operator $H(\epsilon)$ acting on a finite Hilbert space of dimension $\mathbb{C}^N$ (thus the spectrum is discrete), where the parameter $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+_0$. Assume we have a sequence (holomorphic family), $S_n(\epsilon)$, that converges absolutely to $H(\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon\leq \epsilon_c$ with $\epsilon_c\neq 0$:
\begin{equation}
    H(\epsilon)=\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n(\epsilon),
\end{equation}
with the sequence defined as
\begin{equation}
 S_n(\epsilon)=\sum_{i=0}^n\epsilon^iH_i,
\end{equation}
where the $H_i$'s are independent of $\epsilon$.
Assume that I know that for a given $m$, the lowest eigenvalue of $S_m(\epsilon)$ has multiplicity 1 for $0< \epsilon \leq \epsilon_u$, note that the multiplicity could be larger at $\epsilon=0$.
Questions:

Is the lowest eigenvalue of $H(\epsilon)$ guaranteed to have multiplicity 1 for sufficiently small (but $\neq0$) $\epsilon$?

Is there a book or article that states this explicitly?


Remark: If it makes things easier, it could be assumed that $m$ gives the smallest $n$ such that the lowest eigenvalue of $S_n(\epsilon)$ has multiplicity 1 for small $\epsilon$.
Ideas: My intuition is that there should be a way to construct a continuity argument on a disk around $\epsilon=0$ that allows me to connect the lowest eigenvector of $H(\epsilon)$ with the one of $S_m(\epsilon)$.
I think that this is related to the solution to this question: Convergence of spectrum with multiplicity under norm convergence
The main difference is the dependence on $\epsilon$. I believe in our case, we can lift the condition on sufficiently large $n$ (thus fixing it to $m$) by imposing sufficiently small $\epsilon$.
